# How can I hide video tracks in Edge on windows 10?

Tags: javascript, html, video, microsoft-edge, subtitle

I used this code to hide video tracks(subtitle) and it works fine everywhere except in Microsoft Edge on windows 10 (my version is IE13).

```
var myVideoFrame = document.getElementById("myVideoFrame");
myVideoFrame.textTracks[0].mode = "hidden";
```

How can I hide it in other way ?

Comment: thats working for me - can you provide a demo where it is not?

Comment: I do the same with VideoJS and it works fine in Edge, too.  

Do you have a live page that we can view?